# Python Selenium find element by xpath or by id issue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath-2.0

I am trying to enter text into a text box on a web page but I am unable to locate it. I've tried finding it by xpath using the placeholder but may have had the wrong syntax as it was throwing an error.

The error I get with the below python is `element not interactable` - but it's a text field? surely it's intractable?

HTML:

```
<div class="name-filter-input"> == $0
  <input placeholder="Search" ng-model="filter"
  class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
</div>
```

My Python:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('name-filter-input')
campaign_text_field = browser.find_element_by_class_name('name-filter-input')
campaign_text_field.send_keys(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to interact with the division instead of the input field.

Could you try changing the class name as so:

```
campaign_text_field = browser.find_element_by_class_name('ng-pristine ng-valid')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Selector for the input element.

```
campaign_text_field = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input.ng-pristine.ng-valid')
campaign_text_field.send_keys("XXX")
```

---

For the best practice induce WebDriverWait() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input.ng-pristine.ng-valid'))).send_keys("XXX")
```

Add following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```